# How to forward a copy of sent,receiving emails of Google Apps users

Tags: google-apps

In my Google Apps account I am the Administrator. what I need is I would like to track all emails of my users by getting them in my email box. is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2604578?hl=en) about Email Log Search for Google Apps. You will not get the emails in your inbox but you get a track of them in this tool. You also have different search criteria to filter your results.

`Email log search gives administrators the ability to sift through the delivery logs for their domains and evaluate message transit. This is useful for tracking down a sender or recipient's missing messages, such as those that have been quarantined as spam or otherwise routed incorrectly. Use this tool to determine the IP addresses sending and receiving mail or troubleshoot how policies affect mail flow.`